# how to create virtual switch in Hyper-v when host is allocated with static ip?

Tags: hyper-v

Able to create virtual switch using Hyper-v manager, when host is not in static ip mode..
Is there any difference in creating virtual switch using power shell cmdlets and UI

Answer (score 0):

When I use below power shell cmdlets able to add virtual switch in static ip mode.

```
Get-NetAdapter ,
Add-VMNetworkAdapter ,
Set-VMnetworkAdapter
```